# How to solve 'global name not defined' with exec python

Tags: python

I have this code that is throwing an error with exec, and I cant get it to work. It works when
not in a function, though

```
def hashCheck(data):
    exec("hashes = {'hi':'hi'}")  #it was a file import before
    print(hashes['hi'])  #right here is error
    try:
        return(hashes[data]) #and here  is also error
    except KeyError:
        import hashlib
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(data)
        return(m.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Why are you doing `exec("hashes = {'hi':'hi'}")` instead of `hashes = {'hi':'hi'}`?!

Comment: What is your python version? os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your function has no assignments to hashes, python assumes when compiling it that hashes is a global variable. However, when compiling the string for exec, you do have an assignment to hashes so python assumes it is a local variable. So your exec statement assigns to a variable in the local scope, but your print statement looks for it in the global scope.

It may work if you change it to something like:

```
def hashCheck(data):
    hashes = None
    exec("hashes = {'hi':'hi'}")
    print(hashes['hi'])
```

That said, you probably shouldn't be using exec() unless you really know what you're doing and are sure you need it. If you just want some human-readable serialization for simple python objects, you may want to look into something like yaml instead.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for... I realized how bad that code was a few months later XD, but the "hashes = None" should fix the problem, ty :)