# exec() runs differently in command line and script

Tags: python-3.x

When I try exec() to execute this code in python console and script, it has different results

python console:

```
>>> def test():
...     x = 13
...     exec('b = x + 1')
...     print(b)
... 
>>> test()
14
>>>
```

python script

```
def test2():
    x = 13
    exec('b = x + 1')
    print(b)
```

> ```
>   NameError: name 'b' is not defined
> ```

But with this code, they are the same

python console

```
>>> def test1():
...     x = 0
...     exec('x += 1')
...     print(x)
... 
>>> test1()
0
```

python script

```
def test1():
    x = 0
    exec('x += 1')
    print(x)

test1()
# 0
```

Comment: Your first code fragment (`test()`) produces the same error as the second one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve 'global name not defined' with exec python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670295/how-to-solve-global-name-not-defined-with-exec-python)

Comment: In brief: `exec('b = x + 1')` creates a _local_ variable `b`, but `print(b)` attempts to print a _global_ variable that does not exist.

Comment: @DYZ But in python console it doesn't raise any error and b is properly printed

Comment: You probably already defined global variables `b` and possibly `x`. Close the console and start over. You will see the same error message.

Comment: @DYZ Yes exactly, I defined a global variable b before to test how exec() perform out side a function, thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

"""
But with this code, they are the same

python console

```
>>> def test1():
...     x = 0
...     exec('x += 1')
...     print(x)
... 
>>> test1()
0
```

python script

```
def test1():
    x = 0
    exec('x += 1')
    print(x)

test1()
# 0
```

"""

Because with this code, x is define , so your function 'exec()' don't work here
it's the same that you have'nt write 'exec'

Answer (score 0):

But, the reason of the that error is that you didn't define `b`.
That might work

```
def test2():
    x = 13
    exec('b = x + 1\nprint(b)')
```